# container height not scalable

Tags: html, css

I have 2 pictures positioned above eachother within a container. (They are postioned over eachother for a fade effect)

So it looks like:

```
<div id="container">
  <img id="mainpictop" on-load="{{fade}}" src="{{pic1source}}" style="opacity:{{pic1opacity}}">
  <img id="mainpicbottom" on-load="{{fade}}" src="{{pic2source}}" style="opacity:{{pic2opacity}}">
</div>
```

my css is this:

```
#container{
      display: block;
      position: relative;
      overflow: hidden;
      height: 24em;
    }
img {
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      transition: opacity 1s;
      -webkit-transition: opacity 1s;
    }
```

The images are scaling properly but when I put an element under the pictures and I resize the page, there is a gap, because the height of the container stays the same. How can make the container resize? Is there a way using only css and html?

Comment: The only way to achieve that is to remove `position: absolute;` from image and use instead `display:block;` or `display:inline-block;`

Comment: but when I remove the position absolute, I can't let the images lay over eachother, can I?

Comment: you can use 'transform3d' translate on the 2.img or use a `div.clearfix` or `Flexbox `

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't really understand... When I remove the position:absolute; and make the image display:block; the images will be shown under eachother instead of over eachother... 

My animation just makes the opacity of one of the two images 0 or 1 to cycle through them

Answer (score 0):

By default, the "img" element is displayed as inline element. This will add line-height to the image and will cause spacing between images. If you add "display: block", that should resolve the issue, if I am correctly understanding it; unfortunately I can't quite test your example. Another solution is to add font-size: 0 to the parent...

```
#container{
      display: block;
      position: relative;
      overflow: hidden;
      height: 24em;
    }
img {
      position: absolute;
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      transition: opacity 1s;
      -webkit-transition: opacity 1s;
    }
```

Comment: this doesn't solve the problem, I still have to give a height to the container, and when I resize the page, the img will get smaller, but the container-height won't, this creates a gap on the page between the picture and the next element after the container

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to make the page responsive. You should give `min-width` and `max-width` and height vice versa to your content. Or If I could see the actual content or if you could give the jsfiddle example that would great to solve this. :)

Comment: Hi, I would make a jsfiddle but I'm using google polymer for the elements :/  when I set a min-height, the picture doesn't scale properly anymore